# Whats wrong with my if statement

Tags: jquery

I have a simple script which does basic calculations. I have a price which is dynamically populated but the sake of simplicity I set a constant price. The input box which takes the down payment has min and max attributes set. The min is 10% of 3000 which is 300 and max is the 3000. My if statement keeps telling me that the down payment is always either less or more than the min max values unless I use the min or max values. In the fiddle the if statement works with min and max but not on my actual site. Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smash120/t6rfkntb/)  for you to check.

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr id="payment">
    <td>Payment</td>
    <td>$3000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="down_payment">
    <td>Down Payment</td>
    <td>$300</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="financed_amount">
    <td>Amount Financed</td>
    <td>$2700</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="term">
    <td>Term</td>
    <td>22 months</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="interest_rate">
    <td>Interest rate</td>
    <td>0%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="monthly_payment">
    <td>Monthly Payment</td>
    <td>$122.73</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <h5 style="font-size: .9em; text-align: center">Enter higher down payment to lower monthly payment</h5></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="update_button">
    <td>
      <input type="number" value="" min="300" max="3000" name="change_amount" id="change_amount" style="width:100px; margin-left: 24%;" />
      <br>
      <label for="change_amount" class="error" style="display:none;margin-left: 10%;"></label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="Update" name="update_down_payment" id="update_down_payment" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
$('#update_down_payment').click(function(e) {
  var down_payment = $('#change_amount').val();
  var min = $('#change_amount').attr('min');
  var max = $('#change_amount').attr('max');
  alert('down payment=' + down_payment + ' Min=' + min + ' Max=' + max);
  if (down_payment === "" || down_payment > max || down_payment < min) {
    $('.error').text("Please input down payment between " + Number(min).toLocaleString("en-US", {
      style: "currency",
      currency: "USD",
      minimumFractionDigits: 0
    }) + " and " + Number(max).toLocaleString("en-US", {
      style: "currency",
      currency: "USD",
      minimumFractionDigits: 0
    }));
    $('.error').show();
  } else {
    var payment = $("#payment td:nth-child(2)").text().replace(/\D/g, '') * 1;
    var financed_amount = (payment - down_payment);
    $('.error').hide();
    $('#down_payment td:nth-child(2)').text(Number(down_payment).toLocaleString("en-US", {
      style: "currency",
      currency: "USD",
      minimumFractionDigits: 0
    }));
    $('#financed_amount td:nth-child(2)').text(Number(financed_amount).toLocaleString("en-US", {
      style: "currency",
      currency: "USD",
      minimumFractionDigits: 0
    }));
    $('#monthly_payment td:nth-child(2)').text(Number(financed_amount / 22).toLocaleString("en-US", {
      style: "currency",
      currency: "USD",
      minimumFractionDigits: 0
    }));
  }
});
```

Is something wrong with my if statement

Comment: `.val` returns string as well

Comment: Perhaps you may want to convert `min` and `max` to numbers rather than have them be used as strings? Just a thought.

Comment: Btw, here's a Fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/5pbs3vk8/

Comment: JSFiddle auto inserts your script in an on load. Wrap the event assignment in a `$(function() ... });` - see updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/e7f3dq8x/) where I change javascript setting  to "head" and wrapped

Comment: Also please make a function out of your number formatter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will make it work

```
  var min = parseInt($('#change_amount').attr('min'),10);
  var max = parseInt($('#change_amount').attr('max'),10);
```

Comment: Thanks guys I did what JB King stated and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Try the updated Fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/t6rfkntb/8/

```
var min = Number($('#change_amount').attr('min'));
var max = Number($('#change_amount').attr('max'));`
```

Comment: The answer from Enrico may also work but it will always assume your amount is an Int.